# Windows Update service start and stop button are grayed and impossible to start

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-update

In Windows Update service start and stop button are grayed and impossible to start.

When I try to start it via net start command :
net stop wuauserv
Le service démarre ou s'arrête. Faites un nouvel essai plus tard.
("Service is starting or stopping. Try later")

I think the windows update component is corrupt.

[image: Windows Update in services.msc]

Comment: It is possible that service isn't started properly. If it is possible, try rebooting your server.

Comment: We will reboot soon. I didn't found anything for the moment. Thanks

Comment: The command line `sc query wuaserv` should be able to tell you whether it's trying to start or stop.  There may also be information in your Windows Application Log.

Comment: sc query wuaserv
[SC] EnumQueryServicesStatus:OpenService échec(s) 1060 :
Le service spécifié n'existe pas en tant que service installé.

(the specified service does not exist as installed service)

Comment: The reboot and manual start of bits + windows update fixed this, Thanks